# What is the 'answered' statistic?

Tags: support, stats, user-interface, unanswered-questions

Quick question, if anyone knows: On Beta sites, in the small stats box on the homepage, what does the 'answered' statistic represent?

Does it mean:

- questions that have *at least* one answer? or:
- questions that have an *accepted* answer?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Stack Exchange jargon, [“answered” usually means](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/) having an accepted answer or an answer with a positive score. The idea is that if there are answers but they don't have more upvotes than downvotes and none is accepted, then those answers haven't proved their worth.

You can improve this statistic by browsing the [unanswered questions](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/unanswered), answering them, and waiting for an upvote, or by upvoting an existing answer if there is one.

Comment: So we really only have 58% of our questions with an up vote?

Comment: @ṧнʊß Not questions with an upvote, questions with an upvoted answer. [Is it a concern](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/636/is-the-proportion-of-unanswered-questions-a-concern)? [Quite possibly](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/981/is-this-site-viable).

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant.